# Test Kitchen login command failing

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, test-kitchen

I'm following [this](http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started) getting-started guide for test kitchen and made some initial good progress. However when trying to use kitchen login command mentioned on [this](http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started/manually-verifying) page , it fails with 'No such file or directory - ssh' 
My local system is Windows7, can anyone help please?

C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:220:in `exec': No such file or directory - ssh (Errno::ENOENT
)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:220:in`login'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/command/login.rb:39:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:56:in`perform'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:224:in `login'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:308:in`invoke_task'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/bin/kitchen:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:154:in`with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.4.0/bin/kitchen:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/kitchen:23:in`load'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/kitchen:23:in `'

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Cygwin and SSH. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/.  Once you are able to run the 'ssh' command from a windows command prompt you should be able to run the kitchen login command successfully past the current error you are receiving.  The 'kitchen login' command is trying to use ssh to get to the vm but it can't because its not installed/configured on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can log in via vagrant.  Use `vagrant local-status` to get a list of local VMs and their ids.  Then run `vagrant ssh <id>`.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, ChefDK comes embedded with Git for Windows, which includes its own version of ssh.

If you have this issue in Windows, and you have ChefDK installed, then make sure you have the following in your System PATH environment variable (The actual location may vary if you installed ChefDK in a different location):

```
C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\git\usr\bin
```